# Shell Models of Energy Cascade in Turbulence

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, flow, turbulence

I'm looking for introductory material on the subject of Shell Models in Turbulent flows. Text books are preferred, but if not, reviews could be helpful.

[This review](https://www-annualreviews-org.ezproxy.weizmann.ac.il/doi/pdf/10.1146%2Fannurev.fluid.35.101101.161122) is what I want to read, but it assumes many Prerequisites.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your post what your background is, but assuming you have a solid grounding in fluid dynamics, I strongly recommend Uriel Frisch's *Turbulence, the lagacy of A.N. Kolmogorov*, which includes a section on shell models.